lombok: ignore field for builder and requiredArgsConstructor
Here my class:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Slf4j
public class IdentityContextRepositoryImpl implements IdentityContextRepository {

    private final String bucket;
    private final String csvObjectKey;
    private final S3Template s3Template;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Builder.Default
    private final Supplier<List<IdentityContext>> memoizedIdentityContextsWithExpiration = Suppliers
            .memoizeWithExpiration(this::updateIdentityContexts, Duration.ofMinutes(10));

As you see, I've some final fields, and the last one, an already initialized field I want to exclude from builder and constructors.
How could I set lombok ignores this field?
Currently, I'm getting:

Cannot use this in a static context Java

Any ideas?
